# I want to know how can get back my bch

Tags: wallet

I have incorrectly sent bitcoincash to bitcoin wallet address. (from upbit exchange in korea to kucoin exchange in hongkong)

Is there any way to get my bitcoincash back?

Answer (score 2):

As that address belongs to an exchange, the only thing you can do about it is contacting their support (the exchange you sent your coins to).